# How to synchronize data between 2 EBS volumes in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have 2 EBS volumes in 2 availability zones in the same region, one is primary and another is backup. Generally, I just read and write data from primary volume. Is it possible to synchronize data from primary to back up EBS volume? if yes, how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: maybe with rsync

Comment: This is not a features provided by AWS. You will need to use third party software or write your own. Note: Windows and Linux support disk mirroring. Edit your question to be more clear on what type of data synchronization that you require.

Comment: Just checking that you know that EBS volume data is already replicated by AWS across multiple servers in an Availability Zone and you can take incremental snapshots.

Comment: @jarmod, thanks a lot,  it's true that the data will not lose because it's already replicated somewhere else, but you know when the primary EC2 instance failed, I would like to just start my backup instance which with the backup EBS volume mounted.

Comment: @Andrew and John, thanks a lot, I guess you are right no other choice but config by ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use EFS for this? You might be able to avoid having to replicate the data is you can have the primary and backup instance/applications looking at the same data volume.

Comment: EFS could be a option, but seems its performance is not as good as SAN, it's NAS like storage.

Comment: Yes, but you won't get SAN on AWS as it's all Network Attached Storage. What performance level do you need to reach?

Comment: I am not sure what performance level we need right now, we are utilizing EMC vMAX3 in our data center, later we are going to migrate to AWS, maybe we need a verfication in AWS

Comment: That's more of a cost/requirements question that needs answering before you start solutioning a design. If you can determine what performance/reliability is acceptable and then look at existing architecture patterns that can provide that. If there aren't any then you can start looking at what else can be done to get the performance you need.

Answer (score 3):

1 year after this question has been posted but I hope it helps anyone looking into this.

Amazon EFS is a great solution. An alternative for what you require is using Snapshots. With AWS Backup you can schedule Amazon EBS snapshots and have them shared across AZ or even different accounts.

As very well proposed in the previous answer, you should first try to understand your performance requirements for the workload and also the RPO and RTO requirements.

Comparing EFS and EBS, I could say that:
A. EFS (Elastic File System) is a managed parallel NFS (based on NFSv4). You are going to mount it as a directory. EFS leverages the same technology as EBS, and the disks are replicated in the AZ and also between AZ. You don’t chose or control the disks, just what performance you expect from the managed service.

B. EBS (Elastic Block Storage) is also network attached but is a block storage, which means that your OS will see it as a disk and not a directory. You have to format it as a file system (or group it with other EBS and create LVM, RAID, etc) before you can use it. EBS are replicated within the same AZ but not across AZ. You can have snapshots of your EBS and copy them to the other AZ, for example.

So you have to take into account not only the performance you require but also what type of storage (block or file) your application need.